# Unexpected "transient" constructor modifier

Tags: java, reflection, jvm

I found interesting thing while working with reflection. I tried to retrieve constructors of simple class and their modifiers.

```
public class Test {
    public Test(Object... args) {}
}
```

Here is the code to retrieve constructor modifiers:

```
Class<?> clazz = Test.class;
Constructor<?>[] ctors = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors();
for (Constructor<?> ctor : ctors) {        
    int mod = ctor.getModifiers();
    /*if not package-private modifier*/
    if(mod!=0) {
        System.out.println( Modifier.toString(mod)));
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
    public transient
```

If I pass to constructor not variable parameters, but just array, it's ok.

```
public class Test {
    public Test(Object[] args) {}
}
```

The result is:

```
    public
```

The same happens regardless of constructor modifier (public, protected, private) or parameters type (primitive or reference). How could it be, whereas "transient" is not valid modifier for constructor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Access modifiers are encoded as bit masks inside the class file. The JVM spec assigns different meaning to some of the bits depending on whether they appear in a method modifier or a field modifier. Bit 7 (`0x0080`) is one such bit.

[For methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6):

```
ACC_VARARGS    0x0080  Declared with variable number of arguments.
```

[For fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.5):

```
ACC_TRANSIENT  0x0080  Declared transient; not written or read by a persistent
                       object manager.
```

Since you're looking at a method, the correct interpretation of this modifier is `ACC_VARARGS` and not `ACC_TRANSIENT`.

However, the [`Modifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html) class only appears capable of dealing with a subset of modifiers defined in the JVM spec. Because all it takes is an `int`, it's unable to tell `ACC_VARARGS` and `ACC_TRANSIENT` apart.

Comment: Does that count as a bug of the `toString` method?

Comment: @JanDvorak: I am not sure. As things stand, the `Modifier` class only appears capable of dealing with a subset of modifiers defined in the JVM spec (as it's unable to differentiate between modifiers that have the same bit value).

Comment: I'm wondering - why do the bit values actually collide? Isn't that an oversight from the JVM devs?

Comment: I propose a solution that there be _two_ toString methods. One for fields and the other for methods.

Comment: @Jan: only fields can be transient and only methods/constructors can have varargs, so the collision is not problematic in practice. Yes, two `toString` methods would solve this.

Comment: Would it have killed them to have separate bits for transient and varargs? I'm not sure off the top of my head how many modifiers there are, but I'm pretty sure it's less than the number of bits in an `int` (ie 32)